# Animating UIView center property not working on willRotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, animation

I'm animating a subview in the UIViewController's willRotateToInterfaceOrientation. First, I was setting its frame to a new position and it was working fine. Since I just animate the positioning I tried to animate the center property instead. As soon as I do it, the animations do not work anymore.

I'm using UIView's animateWithDuration and when checking the completion block, the finished parameter is always NO. Animating the center property on other events like a button click works fine.

Might it be that the rotation algorithm iOS uses to reposition a view's subviews also touches the center property and cancel's my animation?

Comment: Ok this is strange. I made a test and added a delay to the animation, say 5 seconds, to give the iOS enough time to reposition the view after the rotation. Guess what, as soon as the view finishes rotating, the completion block is called with the finished flag set to NO. Then after 5 seconds the animation does happen but the completion block is not called. WTH!?

Comment: An update. I forgot about the fact that changes to view properties happens immediately whether in an animation block or not. The OS takes care of animating it at the appropriate time, but the property has already changed. Observing the property, it get's changed only once in the willRotate method. Guess I will use didRotateInstead.